# Sort list based on first occurance of elements

Tags: java, list, sorting

I have a Java `List<Integer>` with a collection of values, containing for example:

```
[0, 5, 2, 1, 3, 2, 6, 1, 1, 0, 10]
```

I want to sort the list by the first occurrence of each element, with the following newly sorted list:

```
[0, 0, 5, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 6, 10]
```

The `List` I am dealing with will have max 400-500 elements, so something lightweight is preferred but I can't quite figure out an approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly sort by using the result of `indexOf` (which returns the first index of an element in the list).

```java
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(0, 5, 2, 1, 3, 2, 6, 1, 1, 0, 10);
list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(list::indexOf));
System.out.println(list);
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/9BOzyS)

Comment: This has complexity O(n^2 log(n)), though, right?

Comment: @Stef Yes, but that shouldn't be a problem for just 400-500 elements. It can be optimized by using a `Map` to store the first occurrence of each element.

Comment: Fair point, but still, a complexity more than quadratic, for something that could be linear, at the very least you should put a warning in bold letters in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is even simplier solution with usage of LinkedHashMap, which remembers put order:

```
    List<Integer> source = Arrays.asList(0, 5, 2, 1, 3, 2, 6, 1, 1, 0, 10);
    List<Integer> target = new ArrayList<>();

    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    source.forEach(number -> map.merge(number, 1, Integer::sum));

    map.forEach((key, value) -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < value; i++) {
            target.add(key);
        }
    });

    System.out.println(target);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 data structures:

- a Map to store how many times a number occured
- a List to remember in which order they occurred

This code does what you want:

```
String in = "0, 5, 2, 1, 3, 2, 6, 1, 1, 0, 10";
String[] split = in.split(", ");
List<Integer> lstIn = Arrays.stream(split).map(Integer::parseInt).collect(Collectors.toList());
Map<Integer, Integer> theMap = new HashMap<>();
List<Integer> listOccurence = new LinkedList<>();

for(Integer i:lstIn) {
    theMap.compute(i, (k,v)->v==null?1:v+1);
    if(!listOccurence.contains(i)) {
        listOccurence.add(i);
    }
}
List<Integer> out = new LinkedList<>();
for(Integer i:listOccurence) {
    Integer count = theMap.get(i);
    for(int j=0;j<count;j++) {
        out.add(i);
    }
}
System.out.println(out);
```

This prints:

```
[0, 0, 5, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 6, 10]
```